# Getting python dependency issue when configuring droplet at boot time in digital ocean

Tags: ansible

I am using ansible playbook to create droplet in digital ocean and want to configure it at boot time using ansible. Droplet is creating successfully but when i am trying to configure it at boot time its giving python dependency issue. I am aware about it but now i am confused how we can install it during boot time or on the fly? Below is the my ansible playbook:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
  - name: Create new DO Droplet
    digital_ocean:
     state: present
     command: droplet
     name: ansibletest
     api_token: xyz123
     size_id: '1gb'
     region_id: ams3
     image_id: '39739486'
     ssh_key_ids: '23625890'
    register: my_droplet
  - name: print info about my_droplet
    local_action:
      module:  debug
         msg= "ID is {{ my_droplet.droplet.id }} IP is {{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }}"
  - name: Add new droplet to host group
    local_action: add_host hostname={{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }} groupname=launched
  - name: Wait for SSH to come up
    local_action: wait_for host={{ my_droplet.droplet.ip_address }} port=22 delay=60 timeout=320 state=started
- hosts: launched
  become: true
  gather_facts: True
  tasks:
  - name: installing redis server 
    apt: name=redis-server state=latest
```

Below is the error which i got and its related to python dependency on remote client.

```
fatal: [188.26.76.45]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stderr": "Shared connection to 188.166.71.116 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 127}
```

I didn't phase this issue in AWS because EC2 instance have python2.7. Can you please help me to fix this issue so i can configure digital ocean droplet at boot time using ansible. Any guidance will be appreciated.

I have run the playbook using the below command:
    ansible-playbook droplet.yml --key-file "/etc/ansible/tek.pem"

Thanks.

Comment: Please help me to fix the issue in above post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure the instance using the `raw:` module, which requires only ssh access.

You can see an example of that kind of thing in the [kubespray `bootstrap` role](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/blob/v2.7.0/roles/bootstrap-os/tasks/bootstrap-ubuntu.yml), but the tl;dr is:

```
- hosts: launched
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - raw: |
     set -e
     # but you are responsible for your own idempotent behavior
     if [ -x /usr/bin/python ]; then exit 0; fi
     export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
     apt-get update
     apt-get install -y python
  # now, in theory, you can resume using ansible modules
  # and can do the equivalent of "gather_facts: yes"
  - setup:
  - # etc etc
```

Comment: The main issue is SSH, because ansible server unable to SSH or Ping my client (Digital Ocean droplet) without python-minimal and python-simplejson packages. So how we can install these packages at boot time? Or raw module can help me to fix this issue without installing these packages?

Comment: I don't follow your question; I can assure you that I have used that very `raw:` statement to provision a machine that did not contain one byte of python on it (in fact, CoreOS doesn't even have a package manager at all, so it's possible to be even lower level); did you even **try** what I wrote before commenting?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Its working fine for me. Earlier i didn't try it but i ask my question before using it. Thanks once again.